# GCC inline assembly isn't copying data to input registers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am trying to use BIOS interrupts to read hard disk sectors using the following code:

```
int readSec(char sector, unsigned char out[]) {
  char error = 0;
  int address = (int)out;
  __asm__ __volatile__("xorw %ax, %ax;" //clear all registers
    "xorw %bx, %bx;"
    "xorw %cx, %cx;"
    "xorw %dx, %dx;");
  __asm__ __volatile__("movw $0x00, %%ax; movw %%ax,%%es;" //clear the memory location that the sector will be read into
    "movw $0x0000, %%ax;"
    "movw $512, %%cx;"
    "movw %w0, %%di;"
    "rep stosw;"::"b" (address));
  __asm__ __volatile__(
    "movb $0x02, %%ah;" //read the sector
    "movb $0x01, %%al;"
    "movw %w2, %%bx;"
    "movb %b1, %%cl;"
    "int $0x13;"
    "sbb %w0, %w0;": "=r" (error): "m" (sector), "m" (address));
  return error;
}
```

Upon running this code, nothing happens.

In order to debug the code, I looked at the disassembly, and to my surprise the "address" variable is never copied to `di` - an empty register is copied instead. Here is the disassembly of the function (on the right) and the function itself (on the left):

[image]

As can be seen in the picture, the `bx` register is zeroed (as it is in the first assembly block) and then upon reaching the `movw %w0, %%di` line it simply uses the zeroed `bx` register `mov %bx,%di`. Why does GCC do this? Obviously, copying the value of an empty register to `di` will not copy `address` to it..

EDIT: I am using GCC to compile this code and am running it in a virtual machine. This isn't all of the code either, I just need to know why an empty register is being copied to `%di`

EDIT 2: I have removed the ampersand from `(int) & out;` as advised by nos

Comment: Your code makes no sense.

Comment: @EOF Cheers... I guess...

Comment: You cannot use BIOS interrupts from within Windows programs.

Comment: @FUZxxl I know.. I am only using Visual studio as a code editor. The executable is run in a virtual machine

Comment: Start by putting every assembly instruction on a new line by putting `'\n'` between them. Adjacent string literals are concatenated, no implicit newline is added.

Comment: @EOF That's not the problem, he uses `;` for concattenation instead.

Comment: @EOF Exactly, the semicolon after every statement tells the assembler that the instructions are meant to be on different lines

Comment: Well, that would depend on the assembler. Some use a semicolon to designate the rest of the line as comments.

Comment: @EOF True, but GAS uses it to indicate a new instruction

Comment: @EOF gcc uses the GNU assembler. If you don't know what you are talking about, please do some research before making misleading and wrong comments.

Comment: @FUZxxl: gcc uses the system assembler (which could be something like `gold` instead).

Comment: @EOF gold is a linker, not an assembler.

Comment: @FUZxxl @ EOF Guys, can we please not argue? In my case at least, the generated code clearly shows that my assembler understands my code.

Comment: Note that your `int address = (int) & out;` is wrong, you don't want the address of the pointer you're passing in, drop the `&`

Comment: You have a larger problem than not informing GCC about the registers you clobber. From the disassembly, you're apparently targeting a 32-bit platform.  16-bit real mode BIOS services won't work in that environment; for one thing, the buffer address you're trying to put into `di` is a 32-bit address, so it won't fit in the 16-bit `di` register. Even if you could invoke a BIOS service, you can't tell it the address of the buffer you intend to use.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: The disassembly makes me think he took the output of `gcc -m32 -S` and assembled it in 16bit mode.  (32bit insns have an operand-size and/or address-size prefix, while 16bit insns don't.)  That might still work, except the default stack width won't match, so functions won't find their parameters in the right places.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for pointing that out - I don't think I would have ever noticed that.  So perhaps fixing the clobber spec in the inline GCC code will do the trick then?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: possibly, although I expect there would still be problems, e.g. lack of segment setup.  It's still pretty nasty code.  (e.g. it zeros `%ax` twice: once with xor, then with a `mov $0` to set up for `rep stosw`.)  I'd say removing the `xor`-zeroing block entirely would be good.  Or just write the whole function in NASM syntax!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, lets look at what it is generating for what you specify.  You have:

```
:
"movw %w0, %%di;"
...::"b" (address));
```

This tells the compiler 'copy the value in address into %ebx (the "b" constraint), and generate a `movew %bx,%di` instruction to copy it to %di.  If you look at the generated code, that is exactly what it does:

```
7e62:                       lea   0xc(%ebp),%ebx

7e83:                       mov   %bx,%di
```

its loading the address of the `out` pointer into %ebx as part of initializing `address`, then using it later.

The problem is that you've put in this other block of asm code that clears ebx between these two points without telling the compiler about it.  To fix that, you need to set the 'clobber' on that first block -- append:

```
:::"eax","ebx","ecx","edx".
```

Once you do this, this first block is essentially a noop, telling the compiler to save and restore the values in those 4 registers around the block and otherwise doing nothing.  So you should probably just delete it altogether.

Also, this second asm block is equivalent to:

```
memset(&out, 0, 1024);
```

except much less efficient.  It also just overwrites a big chunk of the stack (since `out` is just a pointer on the stack), which probably results in this code crashing when it tries to return (return address has been overwritten with 0).

In general, you're much better off writing your code in C and only using the inline asm for the code that can't be expressed in C (the `int $0x13` instruction and converting the carry flag to an error code).

Something like:

```
int readSec(char sector, unsigned char out[]) {
    int error;
    memset(out, 0, 1024);  // clear buffer pointed at by out, rather than stack!
    __asm__ volatile(
        "int $0x13;"
        "sbb %0,%0"
        : "=r"(error) : "a"(0x201), "c"(sector), "b"(out))
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not telling the compiler which registers you're clobbering, so it doesn't know which ones it can safely use. Chances are, the address you're after *was* in the bx register from the compiler's point of view. The fact that you're clearing that register in your assembly is not visible to the compiler.

So... You can try to use the [Clobbers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers) argument (after outputs) to the `asm` of the block clearing your registers.

Comment: I tried clobbering the `bx` register in the third asm block but it didn't affect the generated code in the slightest..

Comment: the _first_ block clobbers the registers. You need to tell the compiler that fact.

Comment: Okay, so i changed `"xorw %dx, %dx;");` to `"xorw %%dx, %%dx;":::"bx");` however the code still sadly doesn't change, nor does the outcome..

Answer (score 2):

Apart from not using clobbers properly,this is bad use of inline asm, you should probably do everything in C except for the actual `int 0x13` instruction. Furthermore, registers between asm blocks are not preserved, it's unclear if you expect this or not.

PS: what's the reason for clearing the buffer anyway?

Also note you need to set up `dl` and `dh` too. Try something like:

```
int readSec(unsigned sector, void* out) {
  int error = 0;
  unsigned sector_and_track = sectpr + xxxx; 
  unsigned drive_and_head = xxxx; 
  memset(out, 0, 512);
  __asm__ __volatile__(
    "int 0x13; sbb %0, %0"
    : "=r" (error) : "a" (0x0201), "b" (out), "c" (sector_and_track), "d" (drive_and_head));
  return error;
}
```

Comment: I clear the buffer as a precaution to prevent existing data from misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is going wrong here. I can't tell which one from the information you've provided, but either one of them will prevent this from working.

1. Your CPU is in real mode (16-bit), and is expecting 16-bit instructions. GCC is compiling code with the assumption that it will be run in 32-bit mode; running it in 16-bit mode will cause some instructions to be interpreted incorrectly.

   To be clear, **GCC is not a compiler for 16-bit x86, and cannot be used to compile code to run in real mode.** While some code compiled by GCC will *appear* to work partially in real mode, it will not reliably work correctly.
2. Your CPU is in protected mode (32-bit). BIOS calls do not work in protected mode.

From the context, it looks as though you're trying to write an operating system kernel in C. If you want to do this, you need to either:

- Get the CPU into protected or long mode as quickly as possible, using assembly to do so, then enter C code once it's safe to do so.
- Target another architecture which does not suffer from some of the same initialization "quirks" as x86. ARM is excellent in this regard.

Comment: Nice idea, but according to the disassembly in his `vmware player` window, `xor %ax, %ax` is `31 C0`, while instructions with 32bit addresses and operand sizes are using `67` and/or `66` prefix bytes.  So it looks like somehow he managed to get this code compiled correctly for 16bit.

Comment: For the inline assembly, maybe. Code generated by the C compiler will be another matter entirely.

Comment: No, the assembler sees all instructions in the same file.  "inline asm" instructions aren't assembled separately.  Anyway, even the stack-frame setup `mov %esp, %ebp` is `66 89 E5`, with an operand-size prefix.  It's just some messed-up code.  `int address = (int) & out;`, and then passing that to asm via a `m` constraint (forcing the compiler to store the address into memory) is amusing.